# Java initialize variable or array?

Tags: java

This line of code gives the following warning:

```
    short[] sh = null;

    for (int i = 0, n = b.length; i < n; i++) {
        sh[i] = 0;

    }
```

warning: The variable sh can only be null at this location.

```
short[] sh;

for (int i = 0, n = b.length; i < n; i++) {
    sh[i] = 0;

}
```

And, this code gives the following warning:

warning: The local variable sh may not have been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you need to initialize the array. Try this:

```
short[] sh = new short[b.length];
```

If you don't initialize, you will get those warnings, and will get `NullPointerException` if you run it.

Answer (score 1):

You just declared a variable.

You need to create the array:

```
short[] arr = new short[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

sh will always be null in your code:

```
short[] sh = new short[b.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialization means to create the array, in Java use the "new" keyword

```
short[] arr = new short[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

`sh` is a variable that represents an array of `short`s.

> warning: The variable sh can only be null at this location.

`sh` is initialized but not properly, it is `null`:

```
short[] sh = new short[b.length];
```

> warning: The local variable sh may not have been initialized.

Since the **local variables** are not initialized automatically like **instance variables** you have to initialize it.